# Grant Third Party Application Access to Google Drive API and Admin SDK API of another Organization's Google Workspace

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-workspace, service-accounts, google-directory-api

We are working on a Migration App for Google Drive (Google Workspace) and are relatively new to Google APIs. I read that administrator need to grant **domain-wide delegation of authority** to third-party and internal applications so that they can access users' data such as read Google Drive files.

**Control API access with domain-wide delegation:** https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106

For delegating domain-wide authority to service account, a super administrator of the Google Workspace domain must complete 6 steps as described in the documentation link below:

**Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account:** https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority

As I understand these 6 steps have to be manually performed by Super Admin of the Google Workspace. I would like the super administrator should be able to do these steps easily and quickly. Can this process be automated or guided using some sort of Consent Grant screen in Web Portal.

Instead of using service accounts, can we use OAuth 2.0 Client ID (created within third party app's Google workspace) and consent of Administrator to provide delegated access of their Google Workspace to third party application.
I am asking this because I would need to get list of all users in that Google workspace and have read access to their google Drive files.

**Directory API: Authorize Requests" using Admin SDK:** https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing

**Scope for only retrieving users or user aliases:**  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it is not possible at this moment to manage the domain wide delegation settings through APIs or any different way to automate the process. The Google Workspace Directory API is the only possible way you can use to manage Admin console related settings using the Google APIs, however there is no API method that can make changes like this.

Now, about this:

> Instead of using service accounts, can we use OAuth 2.0 Client ID (created within third party app's Google workspace) and consent of Administrator to provide delegated access of their Google Workspace to third party application.

The only possible way is by adding the application to the domain wide delegation settings, but again, only the admin can add the app manually to their Google Workspace admin console.

Since this is a feature that is not available yet, you could submit a feature request in the Directory API to suggest this as an actual feature and maybe Google can make it available in the near future.

#### Reference:

- [Admin SDK: Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest)
- [Feature request](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/support#developer_product_feedback)

Comment: For anyone wanting this, there's an open issue on Google's issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232839443